# Mazda RX-8 tires squeak when turning while accelerating

Tags: tires, suspension, mazda, lsd, rx-8

This happens a lot when leaving parking lots and making right turns. If I have to turn while accelerating, the rear tires squeak even when I'm not pushing that hard. It sounds like I'm burning out and doing "displays of power" but I'm not. I find it embarrassing, I'm not a teenager and I like to be a courteous driver, especially around the office. I'm not trying to burn out, but it sounds like I am.

Could this be a problem with the LSD? The tires are new, but it happened with the old tires too.

Comment: Have you checked tire pressure against the recommended pressure (usually on the door sill, not on the tire)?  Have to ask...  Could also just be the fact that you have an LSD.  Making a tight turn at a slow speed is going to cause the most speed differential between the inside and outside rear tires.

Comment: What model are the tires? Although, it's probably just because you have a limited slip differential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the LSD.

Depending on the type, if it's a torsen or vicious one then when cold it'll be pretty much locked, and any sharp turn will spin the inside wheel - that's the point of a differential, and more so the exact point of a "limited slip" differential.

You could try changing the diff oil but there's every chance it'll make no difference. Best to check if it also happens when all fluids have warmed up, or worse when cold, then 100% it's the LSD

Answer (score -1):

The wheels are misaligned.  Have a tire shop or front end repair shop perform an alignment.

Comment: That's a good thing to check for others who have this issue, but my car has no alignment problems. I regularly drive it at over 100mph and never had a vibration or pull that would indicate alignment issues.

Comment: Alignment involves more than "pull" or vibration.  The tow needs correction.

Comment: It's actually called toe, and I have no problems with that.